# Django modeling with filmography

Tags: django, django-models

I'm still a beginner in django, and I'm working on a small project.

Lets say I have a list full of actors/actresses along what films they've been in. I also have another list of films with specific details of the film such as date of release, casts, credits etc.

The main goal of the app is to be able to search a specific person and pull up the details of all their films.

So for the models right now I have:

```
class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.TextField()

class Film(models.Model):
     name = models.TextField()
     year = models.IntegerField
```

The Film model will have a lot more information, but I'm not exactly sure how to link the two. For example I want a user to be able type in "Tom Hanks" and then have the details for his 5 most recent movies displayed.

So for the Person model should I add some field that has a list of their films as foreign key somehow, or is there a better way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something like `actors = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name="acted_in")`, `director = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name="directed")`

Answer (score 1):

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()

class Film(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()
   year = models.IntegerField()
   actors = models.ManyToManyField('Person')
```

and then access the film actors using the following command

```
#first get the film from db
f = Film.objects.all()[0] #get the first Film entry
actors = f.actors.all()
```

Comment: But with that setup, how would I be able to grab all the films an actor has been in? Would I need a field in the Person model that lists all the Films?

Comment: @user2027556 Such a field (`film_set`) is created for you implicitly, so you would just use `actor.film_set.all()`. Check the Django documentation on [ManyToManyFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).